# so the argument goes?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Some people have claimed that there is an analogy between the world
> and a work of art. Overall harmony in a piece of music usually
> involves discords which are subsequently resolved; a painting
> typically has large areas of darker as well as of lighter pigment. In
> a similar way, so the argument goes, evil contributes to the overall
> harmony or beauty of the world. This view is also open to at least two
> objections.

Philosophy: The basics

What does "so the argument goes" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means *according to those people*, or *according to their claim*.

"So" means *thus* or *as*.
"the argument" is the reason, or the set of reasons, for their theory.

In your excerpt you might replace "so the argument goes" with the words "they say", or "they argue", or "according to their claim/reasoning".

As JavaLatte says, the speaker may well be distancing him/herself from the claim.

Answer (score 0):

**so the argument goes** is used to explain the logic of another person's opinion. It generally implies that you do not accept the opinion and/or the logic behind it. Here is another example:

> The need to fight the war on terror, **so the argument goes**, necessitates abandoning the prohibition against torture  - *Human rights in the post 9/11 world - Bethany Barratt - 2013*

The logic is that terrorism justifies the use of torture- a view that the author disagrees with.

Comment: @XVI Just to be perfectly clear, "so the argument goes" certainly "generally implies" that the author disagrees with the argument as JavaLatte says, but it does not *assert* such. For example, an author might be explaining the cases for and against universal health care, without taking any position as his own. He might use the term in this context.